# Difference between importing a CSV file and importing a json file into MongoDB

Tags: java, json, mongodb, csv, jackson

I am working on a task where my java program needs to pick to a CSV file from a SFTP server, then convert that CSV into JSON and then import the JSON into MONGODB. I have a java program for converting the CSV to JSON and another java program to import the json into Mongodb. I am having a few issues with these programs when it comes to large data sets, say a million records. My question is, what is the difference between importing the CSV file itself directly into MongoDB and importing a json. I mean, does it make any difference for the data retrieval if the format is different. Also, If I have to enable indexing for this data in Mongodb for elasticsearch purpose, is it good to have the data in json format or it won't matter?. If I have to mix both of my programs into one API where the csv needs to be converted into json and then import the json into Mongodb, how do I make sure that the data import wont start until the conversion is done.
Thanks..

Comment: Have you looked into [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport) ? You can set up some scheduar job which looks for a file in sftp server and when the file is found use the mongoimport to import the csv file into mongodb.

Comment: Ok, say if I am importing the csv file into mongodb, will it be any different from importing a json file into mongo. I mean performace wise, when we try to retrieve the data or indexing the data for elastic search. will the performace be the same?.

Comment: It's just won't work. Mongo stores json documents. It doesn't support any other type.

Comment: So, if I am importing a csv file into mongodb, will it be stored as a json document?. Because when I tried importing a csv file it worked, and I don't see any difference in the data between the csv and json imports, atleast just by looking at the data.

Comment: Yes. There should be no performance difference whether you import csv file ( which are stored as json document ) or insert as json document directly when you access the data. You just can't store the csv data as it will be converted to json document and all the csv key values pairs will be one single json key value pair which is not same as storing json document with all key value pairs.

Comment: Thank you very much @Veeram. Now I understand the difference. You really helped me a lot.